# Why doesn't the integer from variable get_work show up in the print line

Tags: python

```
def get_work(mass, acceleration, distance):
  force = mass * acceleration
  return force
  work = force * distance
  return work

print(get_work(train_mass, train_acceleration, train_distance))

Y = get_work
print("The GE train does " + str(X) + "Joules of work over" + str(Y) + 
"metres.")
```

I am trying to print a sentence that includes the value for get_work, currently it gives me an error value.

Comment: Please give some extra context about the variables with their assigned values

Comment: Once you use the return statement the function is terminated. You can only use one return. Make a list or dictionary if you want to return multiple values.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues here.

Firstly, as Ninad points out, once your function hits the first return statement, it returns, and so it will never hit the rest of the code. It sounds like the thing you actually want to return is the work, not the force, so remove that first return statement:

```
def get_work(mass, acceleration, distance):
  force = mass * acceleration
  work = force * distance
  return work
```

Secondly, you're printing the result of calling the function, rather than assigning it to the Y variable. The thing you do assign is a reference to the function itself, not the return value. Remove that first print statement and assign instead:

```
Y = get_work(train_mass, train_acceleration, train_distance)
```

Finally, it seems that your print statement are in the wrong order. You want to print Y in the place of the work, and `train_distance` in the other place:

```
print("The GE train does " + str(Y) + "Joules of work over" + str(train_distance) + "metres.")
```

Note, that would be better done using `format` with placeholders:

```
print("The GE train does {} Joules of work over {} metres.".format(Y, train_distance))
```

Answer (score 1):

When calling the method get_work(mass, acceleration, distance), you need to call it like this:

```
Y = get_work(train_mass, train_acceleration, train_distance)
```